# Registration form in CQ5

Tags: forms, registration, aem

I need to create a E-mail registration form using CQ5 forms, but its has to be combination of built in compoenets.

Example - It should be a kind of compoenent shown in the sidekick, say 'register' compoenent/form. here author should be able to drag & drop this register component/form & it should have all the values inside like First Name, last name, email, password ect, with a submit button which should go to form submission.

Any views on this, please share.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking — it sound like you're saying that you want don't want to create a custom component, but you do want the OOTB components to behave differently. You can't have both! :)

Comment: @anotherdave I want to create a customize fully functional regiatration form with inbuilt fields on it? Is it possible?

Comment: As *user1723204* says below, you can include components in one another, though I think you'll need some custom development on top — e.g. if it's a registration component, it will need some type of flow of control to it that will be specific for your use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom component with form inside jsp along with submit button include. Inside the form use a parsys(for adding field components like textfield, dropdown, hidden fields. which are there in **generic form block** group in sidekick). Then write a servlet to submit from the form. This way only form path and submit button will be fixed rest of fields author can it anytime any number.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own components. in those components you can then include other compontent. For example if i wanted to include a parsys inside my component i would get something like

mycomponent.jsp

```
 <cq:include path="myparsys"  resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

This way you can create your own components consisting of build in components.